# How do you configure meson to use the zig cc or zig c++ compiler in a build environment for compiling c or c++ code?

Tags: c++, c, meson-build, zig

I have zig installed under `/usr/local/bin/zig`, zig version 0.11.0.

I have environment variables `$ZIGCC = 'zig cc'` and `$ZIGCPP = 'zig c++'` set in my Fish shell config, and I tried setting my default compiler for a C language project with meson as:

```
CC=$ZIGCC meson setup build-zig
```

...for a build directory with zig as the C compiler.

I get this error:

```
meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unable to detect linker for compiler `zig cc -Wl,--version -L/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include
```

I should note `/usr/local/opt/qt@5` is a directory on my fish_user_paths environment variable.

I thought zig was a drop-in compiler for gcc and clang. On Makefiles, I could just do:

```
make CXX=$ZIGCC MyExecutable.exe
```

or

```
make CXX=$ZIGCPP MyExecutable.exe
```

...for C++ and it would just work no need to specify a linker.

Comment: If you run the problematic command directly (`zig cc -Wl,--version -L/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include`), does it work?  It should, which implies something else is going wrong before zig gets invoked.   (Is that the full error message, it looks like it might be truncated?)

Comment: Here's the output from meson-logs.txt: Running command: zig cc -E -dM -
-----
-----------
Detecting linker via: `zig cc -Wl,--version -L/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include` -> 0
stdout:
zig ld 0.11.0
-----------

meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unable to detect linker for compiler `zig cc -Wl,--version -L/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include`
stdout: zig ld 0.11.0      It looks like it is detecting zig ld 0.11.0, but I'm still getting the error emssage that it can't find the linker.

Comment: Given the hacky code in Meson that parses the stdout of the linker's output to figure out which linker is which (see https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/5b16e830cc40827369cf3949a337112be74dec0e/mesonbuild/linkers/detect.py#L118) I'm going to guess that Meson doesn't know what to do with the Zig version number that gets returned.  Can you set an option in Meson to force the linker version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**workaround for c++:**

- configure Meson with your default compiler set on `CXX`(clang++/g++) this will generate a directory with a `build.ninja` file...
- sostitute in the `build.ninja` all the references of your defalut compiler (`clang++` in my case) with `zig c++` (im my case are just 2 replacement but you can automate with script)
- run `ninja` in the setup dir as usual

for me it work

Comment: Hey just tried it and it works for me too. It's weird that meson has no built-in support for zig compiler.

Comment: sorry idk, maybe you could try open an issue on meson github